# combine cucumber, selenium, sikulix and robotium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber, robotium

I have just started to build up a test framework where I test both an Java client and a web client. This is at the moment done with sikulix and selenium. I use cucumber and it is all interacting very nice together. But now I need to start testing an android application. Unfortunately the web client and android application need the java client to be tested and that is way I needed sikulix from the start. This is the background and now the problem:
I need my robotium test project to interact with my cucumber teature files that is placed in the same project as my sikulix and selenium project. Is this doable? If so where should I start?

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Robotium` in that case you can try to use:

- `Selendroid` is a test automation framework which drives off the UI of Android native and hybrid applications (apps) and the mobile web.

  Website: http://selendroid.io/

  GitHub: https://github.com/selendroid/selendroid

  Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MbXLiTHXfE
- `calabash-android` - Automated Functional testing for Android based on `cucumber`.

  Website: http://calaba.sh/

  GitHub: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android

I haven't any experienced with any of these, but especially first might be helpful for your project's test impplementing